# How to handle elements with type = "hidden" in Serenity BDD?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

In our website (written in .Net), there are textboxes, dropdowns, checkboxes etc. with `<input type="hidden">`. I am using Serenity BDD framework with Page Object Model + Java.

I am unable to perform any operation on these elements.

Could someone please help/suggest how to handle such elements?

Note: This elements are visible on website and I could edit and save without any problem.

Steps:

1. locate element using id/name/xpath
2. type/select/expand

Code for one of the textbox:

```
<div class="fhfhfhfh"><input class="hfhfhfhf" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="0" id="text_id" aria-required="true" value="42" aria-invalid="false"><input type="hidden" name="text.Value" value="42"></div>
```

Error:

> net.thucydides.core.webdriver.exceptions.ElementShouldBeEnabledException:
>   Expected enabled element was not enabled

Comment: As per https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden, the element should not be visible. Not sure why they are visible for you. Because of these properties the selenium finds that it is not enabled. Maybe you should talk to your developers.

Comment: @Raju thanks for the answer..I will check...is there a way we could handle these elements?

Comment: what do you mean by handling the elements? Could you be more specific?

Comment: From the HTML example you provided, there are **two** `input` elements. The **first** one does not have the hidden attribute. Did you try interacting with that one?

Comment: @SiKing thanks..I did notice the same and wrote dynamic xpath for that..and it worked..